# AS3 error from Twitter search xml file

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, twitter, rss

I am simply trying to trace search results from twitter.

When I look up a person's timeline, it works perfect:

this is my code:

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?         screen_name=docceng"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML); 

function processXML(e:Event):void{ 
var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
trace(myXML.status[0].id);
trace(myXML.status[0].text);
trace(myXML.status[0].user.name);
}
```

When I try to pull the search results for example:

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=mobile%20ads"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML); 

function processXML(e:Event):void{ 
var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
trace(myXML.entry[0].content);
```

}

I get an error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>     at test_fla::MainTimeline/processXML()  at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Any help for the newbie appreciated.

THanks in advance

dg

Answer (score 1):

The URL is invalid. it should be `http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=mobile%20ads` (no space)

Also entry is an array so you have to write: `trace(myXML.entry[0].content);` instead of `trace(myXML.entry.[0].content);` (mind the extra dot)

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, with the corrections I am still getting the same error. When I visit the 2 different urls they are formatted differently. I think it has something to do with this. THanks again

Comment: Maybe you can try some other XML parser to see if the feed is valid XML or flash side XML parser fails.